# Make HTML Audio file to be played only once?

Tags: html, audio, autoplay

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750082/is-it-possible-to-make-html-audio-file-to-be-played-only-once) topic, this question is answered. But, what if a page is made up of multi pages where pressing next/previous forces the audio to play again. How can we prevent the audio from being played more than once even if we navigate page...
Any solution?

I did the steps written on the linked post, but there is one more thing I need to solve!

Comment: Show your code...